# iOS example using Google SignIn and google spreadsheet api

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-signin

I have been trying to use google signin, which is now required, with google spreadsheet api. There are 2 google examples.

I've followed:

1. ["Google sheets iOS Quickstart"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)
2. ["Start Integrating Google SignIn.."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

Each example works on its own. It's when I try to put the two APIs together things fall apart. The failures are too numerous to list here. Most of the problems stem from my poor understanding of cocoa pods and working with Xcode frameworks.

Can anyone explain how google signin should free up google sheets API?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is not recommended for the Sheets API to use Google Sign in, but if you still want to integrate Google Sign in on your application, then the 2nd link that you provide will help you. If you have difficulties in understanding on how to use cocoa pods and Xcode, I suggest you to check this [documentation](https://www.appcoda.com/cocoapods/) on how to use CocoaPods in your Swift and Objective-C projects. This docu has a screenshot and sample code that you can use as a guide. If you decide to not use cocoa pods, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get the API's to work. There was another Google video that helped. ["Sign in series #3: Advanced Topics in Google Sign-in."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_1105241289&feature=iv&src_vid=QmnI5c85sf0&v=XdhvnywOcvo)

After a quite a bit of searching I now have my app adding data to a Spreadsheet! Yeah!

A few things about that.

1. I had to use GTLServiceDrive(), I couldn't get GTLRSheetsService() work.
2. Use `service.fetchObject(byInserting: ...`. It does a POST call

Comment: @S'rCat...Please provide ur answer here.....am facing problem while deleting data from spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to add a delay to allow Google Signin to authenticate before using the credentials with my GTLRSheetsService object. So I used `[self performSelector:@selector(Method) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0 ];` to delay my code for 3 seconds after calling `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];` and then passing the credentials via `sheetsService.authorizer = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer;`